# Set cron's maximum run counter

Tags: cron

How do I setup cron to run only for a specific number of times? Let's say I want to setup cron so that it runs hourly, but when the scheduler has already run five times, I want to stop cron. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my best knowledge there is no way to run cron for a specific number of times.

As a workaround you could implement i.e. counter in text file, to count how many times the command has been already launched.

Then, in cron, your command has to be wrapper in short script (i.e. `bash`) which would include condition to check how many times the command has been already launched. The exemplary code below:

> counter = read_counter;
>
> if [ counter < 5 ]; then
>
> launch_command;
>
> increment_counter;
>
> fi

I hope I helped somehow.